# How to divide 2 numbers in paillier cryptosystem?

Tags: encryption, biginteger, division

I have encrypted 2 numbers using paillier cryptosystem. encrypted value of the numbers are bigInteger when I want to divide them the value is the decimal number 
for example: first encrypted value of a 9 is 12446486760457687016046
and encrypted value of 3 is 98647617673416817617. the result of division is likely to be decimal. and final result is 0 in this case because paillier get bigInteger as parameter. how can I divide them?

```
    public class Paillier {

/**
* p and q are two large primes. 
* lambda = lcm(p-1, q-1) = (p-1)*(q-1)/gcd(p-1, q-1).
*/
private BigInteger p, q, lambda;
/**
* n = p*q, where p and q are two large primes.
*/
public BigInteger n;
/**
* nsquare = n*n
*/
public BigInteger nsquare;
/**
* a random integer in Z*_{n^2} where gcd (L(g^lambda mod n^2), n) = 1.
*/
private BigInteger g;
/**
* number of bits of modulus
*/
private int bitLength;

/**
* Constructs an instance of the Paillier cryptosystem.
* @param bitLengthVal number of bits of modulus
* @param certainty The probability that the new BigInteger represents a prime number will exceed (1 - 2^(-certainty)). The execution time of this constructor is proportional to the value of this parameter.
*/
public Paillier(int bitLengthVal, int certainty) {
KeyGeneration(bitLengthVal, certainty);
}

/**
* Constructs an instance of the Paillier cryptosystem with 512 bits of modulus and at least 1-2^(-64) certainty of primes generation.
*/
public Paillier() {
KeyGeneration(512, 64);
}

/**
* Sets up the public key and private key.
* @param bitLengthVal number of bits of modulus.
* @param certainty The probability that the new BigInteger represents a prime number will exceed (1 - 2^(-certainty)). The execution time of this constructor is proportional to the value of this parameter.
*/
public void KeyGeneration(int bitLengthVal, int certainty) {
bitLength = bitLengthVal;
/*Constructs two randomly generated positive BigIntegers that are probably prime, with the specified bitLength and certainty.*/
p = new BigInteger(bitLength / 2, certainty, new Random());
q = new BigInteger(bitLength / 2, certainty, new Random());

n = p.multiply(q);
nsquare = n.multiply(n);

g = new BigInteger("2");
lambda = p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).multiply(q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)).divide(
p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).gcd(q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));
/* check whether g is good.*/
if (g.modPow(lambda, nsquare).subtract(BigInteger.ONE).divide(n).gcd(n).intValue() != 1) {
System.out.println("g is not good. Choose g again.");
System.exit(1);
}
}

/**
* Encrypts plaintext m. ciphertext c = g^m * r^n mod n^2. This function explicitly requires random input r to help with encryption.
* @param m plaintext as a BigInteger
* @param r random plaintext to help with encryption
* @return ciphertext as a BigInteger
*/
public BigInteger Encryption(BigInteger m, BigInteger r) {
return g.modPow(m, nsquare).multiply(r.modPow(n, nsquare)).mod(nsquare);
}

/**
* Encrypts plaintext m. ciphertext c = g^m * r^n mod n^2. This function automatically generates random input r (to help with encryption).
* @param m plaintext as a BigInteger
* @return ciphertext as a BigInteger
*/
public BigInteger Encryption(BigInteger m) {
BigInteger r = new BigInteger(bitLength, new Random());
return g.modPow(m, nsquare).multiply(r.modPow(n, nsquare)).mod(nsquare);

}

/**
* Decrypts ciphertext c. plaintext m = L(c^lambda mod n^2) * u mod n, where u = (L(g^lambda mod n^2))^(-1) mod n.
* @param c ciphertext as a BigInteger
* @return plaintext as a BigInteger
*/
public BigInteger Decryption(BigInteger c) {
BigInteger u = g.modPow(lambda, nsquare).subtract(BigInteger.ONE).divide(n).modInverse(n);
return c.modPow(lambda, nsquare).subtract(BigInteger.ONE).divide(n).multiply(u).mod(n);
}

/**
* main function
* @param str intput string
*/
public static void main(String[] str) {
/* instantiating an object of Paillier cryptosystem*/
Paillier paillier = new Paillier();
BigInteger o1 = (paillier.Encryption(new BigInteger("9")));
BigInteger o2 = (paillier.Encryption(new BigInteger("3")));
BigInteger od = o2.divide(o1);
System.out.println(paillier.Decryption(od));
```

Comment: This answer may provide some insight: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2076/division-in-paillier-cryptosystem. At least the first 3 words of it.

Comment: You just want to divide the encrypted representation of the numbers? Is the question in any way different from asking "How do I divide one BigInt into another?"

Comment: @Eric J. This is homomorphic encryption: something like "the result of the addition of crypted arguments, once decoded, is the sum of the original numbers". But with this method, it does not hold for division apparently.

Comment: Except I did not look at the second answer that claims it is possible ^^

Comment: This is the same question again with a different account. You've been asked before to provide the full code and you've been given a good suggestion. Have you tried the suggestion?

Comment: I want to divide the encrypted representation of the numbers

Comment: Ok, but you should provide the information you've been asked about. Otherwise, we can't help you.

Answer (score 2):

As [I explained before,](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36802667/3474) in cryptographic applications, it is common to use the multiplicative inverse instead of division.

In grade school, I learned to divide 9 by 3: 9 ÷ 3 = 3. A bit later I learned that *multiplying* by the reciprocal of the divisor would do the same thing: 9 × ⅓ = 3. For rational numbers, ⅓ is the *multiplicative inverse* of 3: 3 × ⅓ = 1

In modular arithmetic, the multiplicative inverse is analogous to a reciprocal. Suppose I'm working with numbers modulo 256. I want to "divide" by 3. As above, I can do it using the multiplicative inverse of the "divisor". 3 × 171 mod 256 = 1, so 171 is the multiplicative inverse of 3. But wait, 9 × 171 = 1539. Shouldn't it be 3? Oh, wait, we forgot that we are working modulo 256: 1539 mod 256 = 3.

In your example, you have two numbers that could be used as a modulus, `n` or `nsquare`. I believe that if you [study a bit,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paillier_cryptosystem#Homomorphic_properties) you'll discover which to use when performing homomorphic arithmetic with Paillier. Then you can use the [`modInverse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modInverse-java.math.BigInteger-) function to perform your "subtraction".

```
Paillier paillier = new Paillier();
BigInteger o1 = (paillier.Encryption(new BigInteger("9")));
BigInteger o2 = (paillier.Encryption(new BigInteger("3")));
BigInteger od = o1.multiply(o2.modInverse(???));
System.out.println(paillier.Decryption(od));
```

Comment: Is it possible to divide two encrypted numbers in paillier cryptosystem? Suppose that we have [A] and [B] and we want to calculate A / B,  Is this possible at all??

Comment: @Nooshinsalekfaramarzi Yes. I showed that above for A = 9 and B = 3.

Comment: Yes the above example is for dividing two encrypted numbers, which finally results in subtraction operation (results in 9-3=6). What I exactly need is 9/3 = 3. Is this possible for paillier cryptosystem? thanks for your helps.

Comment: @Nooshinsalekfaramarzi I apologize for the mistake. No, you can't compute the product or quotient of *two* encrypted numbers. You *can,* however, compute the quotient of an encrypted number and an un-encrypted number.

Answer (score 0):

Paillier is not homomorphic with respect to the multiplication. You can perform this operation for an algorithm that homomorphic with respect to the multiplication. RSA and ElGamal are multiplicatively homomorphic algorithms. Luckily, they are both wrapped in LightPHE.

```py
# !pip install lightphe
from lightphe import LightPHE
from lightphe.models.Ciphertext import Ciphertext

# build a multiplicatively homomorphic cryptosystem - RSA or ElGamal
cs = LightPHE(algorithm_name = "RSA")

# public modulo of the cryptosystem
modulo = cs.cs.modulo

# define plaintexts
m1 = 9
m2 = 3

# calculate ciphertexts
c1 = cs.encrypt(m1)
c2 = cs.encrypt(m2)

# perform homomorphic operation
# c1 / c2 = c1 * c2 ^ -1
c3_value = c1.value * pow(c2.value, -1, cs.cs.modulo)

# create a ciphertext object from its value
c3 = Ciphertext(
   algorithm_name = "RSA",
   keys = cs.cs.keys,
   value = c3_value,
)

assert cs.decrypt(c3) == m1 / m2
```